# refacto a very big switch

Tags: javascript, node.js, refactoring

I am currently refactoring code JS but I block on a switch that I can not simplify, someone would have an opinion on the question?

For the simulation it is a question of detecting the name of a function, if one has a correspondence, one passes to the stage of after adding a code specific to the function

```
            let getCodeFunctionOfLibrary = (functionName) => {
                try {
                    switch (functionName) {
                        case libCalcul.calculFieldSubstract.name:
                        case libCalcul.calculFieldDevide.name:
                        case libCalcul.calculFieldMultiply.name:
                        case libCalcul.calculFieldSubstract.name:
                        case libCalcul.calculFieldSum.name:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode(libCalcul.calculFieldDevide, libCalcul.calculFieldMultiply, libCalcul.calculFieldSubstract, libCalcul.calculFieldSum);
                            break;

                        case libComparValue.compareValue.name:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode(libComparValue.compareValue);
                            break;

                        case libCreatSVG.createSvgElement.name:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode(libCreatSVG.createSvgElement);
                            break;

                        case libDate.calculDateSubstract.name:
                        case libDate.calculDateSum.name:
                        case libDate.compareDate.name:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode(libDate.calculDateSubstract,
                                libDate.calculDateSum,
                                libDate.compareDate);
                            break;

                        case libDateToValue.transformDateToFieldValue.name:
                        case transformFieldToDate.name:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode(libDateToValue.transformDateToFieldValue,
                                libValueToDate.transformFieldToDate);
                            break;

                        case libDisable.disableField.name:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode(libDisable.disableField,
                                libDisable.disableBooleanField,
                                libDisable.disableDateField,
                                libDisable.disableFileField,
                                libDisable.disableTextareaField,
                                libDisable.disableCustomField);
                            break;

                        case libPopupLink.popupLink.name:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode(libPopupLink.popupLink);
                            break;

                        case libPreFill.preFillField.name:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode(libPreFill.preFillField);
                            break;

                        case libRemoveOption.removeOption.name:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode(libRemoveOption.removeOption);
                            break;

                        case libSecuFrench.controlFrenchSocialSecurityNumber.name:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode(libSecuFrench.controlFrenchSocialSecurityNumber);
                            break;

                        case libSelectSurveyAnswer.selectSurveyAnswer.name:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode(libSelectSurveyAnswer.selectSurveyAnswer);
                            break;

                        case libStartSurvey.addStarSurveyClass.name:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode(libStartSurvey.addStarSurveyClass);
                            break;

                        case libUnauthorizadeCharacters.unauthorizedCharacter.name:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode(libUnauthorizadeCharacters.unauthorizedCharacter);
                            break;

                        default:
                            getLibraryFunctionCode();
                    }

                } catch (error) {
                    console.log(error.message);
                }
            };
```

Comment: Why do you want to refactor it particularly ? Seems correct to me.

Comment: it's a case study we've been given

Comment: I'm not going to complete you course work for you, its not really the purpose of stackoverflow. If you would post what you have tried maybe someone can help. Having said that have you tried looking into the strategy pattern? It's a way to organise control flow code like you are with the switch statement.